# "Unity3D" Index Out Of Range Exception: Array index is out of range (trying to change sprite when hit)

Tags: c#, arrays, unityscript, unity-game-engine

Good morning Developers I know that this question has been asked before but I didn't find a solution to my problem in those answers, first I'd like to tell you that I'm just a beginner in unity :p , well here is my problem : I'm building a brick breaker game what I'm trying to do is to change the sprite of a brick when it gets hit by the ball, to do so I'm using this script :

```
 public int maxHits;
 public int timesHit;
 private LevelManager levelManager;
 public Sprite[] hitSprites;

 void Start () {
     timesHit = 0;
     levelManager = GameObject.FindObjectOfType<LevelManager> ();
 }

 void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision) {
     print ("collison");
     timesHit++;
 }

     // Update is called once per frame
 void Update () {
     if (timesHit >= maxHits) {
         Destroy (gameObject);
     } else {
         LoadSprite ();
     }
     }

 void LoadSprite(){
         int spriteIndex = timesHit - 1;
         this.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ().sprite = hitSprites     [spriteIndex];
     }
 }
```

but I'm getting this error : `IndexOutOfRangeException: Array index is out of range. Brick.LoadSprite () (at Assets/Scripts/Brick.cs:34)`

and I'm getting it every frame!, so it's slowing the game scene too much and I can't test my game anymore. Can you please tell me what did i do wrong and how to fix it?It may help if you direct me to a course to learn more about my error and not't do it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Programmer @Dan-Cook @user2867426
fist, i'd like to thank you all for your answers, i learned so much from you guys so, big thank you!!
well i kinda by mistake fixed my error lol.
when i was optimising my code i noticed that i was using this if condition in the update() while i could use it directly to OnCollisionEnter2D():

```
if (timesHit >= maxHits) {
     Destroy (gameObject);
 } else {
     LoadSprite ();
 }
```

and somehow that fixed my problem i don't know how,
maybe the problem was that it was called every single frame and now it's not!
if you guys could explain to me how moving that if condition from update() fixed the problem i really appreciate it ^^
thank you all ones again.

Comment: lol accepting answer then un-accepting it.... To answer your question, that's because calling it from the `OnCollisionEnter2D` will only call it when there is actually a hit. But when you move the code  to the `Update` function, it is called 60 times per second or every frame regardless of if there is a hit or not. Happy coding!

Comment: @Programmer aaah ok i understand better now, so what was happening is that before any hits were done the timesHit was = 0; and since spriteIndex = timesHit - 1; then spriteIndex was getting -1 and that's what was causing the problem!!
so another way to fix it, is by adding " if(timeshit < 1) return; " to the top of LoadSprite() method 
this will prevent spriteIndex from getting a value of -1 :D

Comment: Yes, that's correct. You should also make sure that the length is not more than or equals to the length of `hitSprites` too. `hitSprites.Length - 1`.  I explained this in my answer.

Comment: @Programmer
Yes thank you that helped me a lot ^^ I have another question to ask i'm trying to do something in my game but i'm having a bug and it does not run perfectly, is there a way to private message you, i'd really appreciate your help ^^

Comment: If you are new to Unity ,You need to do Unity tutorials from [Unity](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials). This will get you get you started. If you don't do this, you will have hard time making anything productive in Unity. There are many complete projects to follow on that link.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because your times hit starts at 0, then when you load a sprite you deduct 1 giving you -1. In the following line of LoadSprite you then attempt to access your hitSprites array at index -1 (hitSprites[-1]) which of course, is out of bounds.

At the very least, I would add some validation to check the bounds of your index.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell tell what you are doing but you are getting that error because you are accessing index that is >= `hitSprites` length.

You should check if `spriteIndex`  variable is less than `hitSprites` length before using it.

Your new `LoadSprite` function should be:

```
void LoadSprite()
{
    int spriteIndex = 0;

    //Don't decrement if timesHit  is 0
    if (timesHit > 0)
    {
        spriteIndex = timesHit - 1;
    }
    else
    {
        spriteIndex = timesHit;
    }

    //Return/Exit function if spriteIndex  is equals or more than hitSprites length
    if (spriteIndex > hitSprites.Length - 1)
    {
        return; 
    }
    this.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = hitSprites[spriteIndex];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to clamp spriteIndex not to go less then 0 (first array index) and over hitSprites.Length reduced by 1 (last array index).

```
void LoadSprite(){
         int spriteIndex = Mathf.Clamp(timesHit - 1, 0, hitSprites.Length - 1);
         this.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ().sprite = hitSprites [spriteIndex];
     }
 }
```

Tip:
dont call too many GetComponent in Update.. Prefetch all components in awake for later use.

```
private SpriteRenderer _spriteRenderer;

void Awake()
{
_spriteRenderer = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ();
}
```